# How to find data between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I do not use Excel regularly, hence I am unfamiliar with complicated formulas.
  I have an Excel 2007 sheet like this:

```
      A           B                  C
    Name      leavefrom          leaveupto
    Mathew    07-Mar-13          25-Mar-13
    john      12-Mar-13          15-Mar-13
    kerry     18-Apr-13          25-Apr-13
    Mikes     27-Jun-13          03-Jul-13
```

and I have a cell **C10** where I am providing a date value.  If I am providing 14-mar-13 then it should show the name "john" and "Mathew", if I provide 19-Apr-13 it should show "kerry", etc...  Basically, if I provide a date value it should find the names who are on leave on that particular date.

Can someone help me find the correct formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you imply you might need to return multiple names, I would suggest the Advanced Filter.  Look at HELP for how to set it up.  But assume that you enter the date into cell G1.  Your Criteria Range might look like (showing the formulas and not the results that show in those cells)

```
leavefrom       leaveupto
 ="<="&D1        =">="&D1
```

Post back if you need more help

Here's a picture of using the Advanced Filter.  Note the options in the Dialog Box to "Copy to another location", and the address to "copy to"

[image]

One can develop macro code to automate the updating of the advanced filter, if this is what you want to do.  First make sure the filter does what you require.

Here is Macro Code to run after the date has been changed by your user.  See if it works for you.  You will likely have to modify it for your specific situation.

If it works, you can set up a button to run it.  If that also works, you can develop code to trigger it by an appropriate Event, to completely automate things.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LeaveList()
    Dim rDateCheck As Range
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rCriteria As Range
    Dim rRes As Range

Set rDateCheck = Range("G1") 'or wherever you have the date
    If Not IsDate(rDateCheck) Then
        MsgBox "You MUST enter a Date!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Set rRes = Range("I1") 'or wherever you want the results
    rRes.Resize(columnsize:=3).EntireColumn.Clear

With Cells
    Set rSrc = .Find(what:="Name", after:=Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    'assume LeaveTable separated from rest of sheet by at least one empty
    '   column and row
    Set rSrc = rSrc.CurrentRegion
End With

'Move Leave Table to leave room for Criteria Range
With rSrc
    If .Row < 5 Then _
        Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(5 - .Row)).Insert shift:=xlDown
End With

'Put Criteria Range above Table
Set rCriteria = Cells(1, rSrc.Column).Resize(2, 2)
    rCriteria.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    rCriteria(1, 1) = rSrc(1, 2)
    rCriteria(1, 2) = rSrc(1, 3)
    rCriteria(2, 1).Formula = "=""<="" & " & rDateCheck.Address
    rCriteria(2, 2).Formula = "="">="" & " & rDateCheck.Address

   rSrc.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCriteria, rRes
End Sub
```

Comment: i would like to get the value in another sheet cell, thanks alot

Comment: One of the options for the Advanced Filter is to place the results in another location.  There is no need to "Filter in Place"

Comment: it is an exciting remark for me can u please refer an example, i am not expert in excel, but very eager to know...

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example of using Advanced Filter.  The formulas are listed above it; and you can see how they show in yellow. Note how you can copy the results to another place. But you'll need to review HELP for the Advanced Filter in order to understand how to use it properly.

Comment: You could use an Event macro to trigger the filter; e.g. Worksheet_Change with Target being the Date that your interested in; or you could connect the Macro to a Button, or a shortcut key; or both -- one for the date change; and the button for changes in the data range.

Comment: I have edited my response to show the macro code.  I will leave it to you to figure out how to attach a button and/or trigger it with event code.

Comment: I again edited the macro to improve the conditional formatting setup, so as not to grey out the labels row

Comment: in the above sheet in yellow color you have given a number 41347 what is that my date may change as per the user selection how to link the filter to cell value(date), thanks alot for your patience pls adivce further

Comment: Well, I am pretty embarrassed. The code I added above was from a completely different and unrelated problem. So I have removed it.  However, it is clear from your question about the criteria range that you do not yet understand the workings of the Advanced Filter.  This is critical, so please review that in Help so you can understand what is going on, and understand what you are seeing in the yellow criteria range and how it gets updated. Only after you are clear about that, and can run the routine manually, should we proceed to automating it.

Comment: sorry for embarrassing you again and again, but i am determined to learn from you please bear with me, my problem is the leave data is being entered by the another person, the manager will be given a field where he will enter the date using calendar and as per the date we have to show the employees on leave on that day, how to dynamically filter this, I honestly request you to solve this one please

Comment: i am using this formula (INDEX(leaveData!A1:D968, SMALL(INDEX((Sheet1!C3<=leaveData!D1:D968)*(MATCH(ROW(leaveData!D1:D968), ROW(leaveData!D1:D968)))+(Sheet1!C3>leaveData!D1:D968)*1048577, 0, 0),ROW($A$2)),COLUMN($A$1)) but it is giving all the leave records whose leave upto date is greater than the selected date, problem in this is...if user selects 14-mar-13, it is showing all the records whose leave upto date is greater than 14-mar-13, but what I desire is the leave records whose leavefrom date is berfore 14-mar13 and leaveupto date is greater than 14-mar-13, please I request you to help

Comment: I have shown you how the Advanced Filter can be used.  Merely modify it so as to use the date from your calendar selection instead of the date entry field I provided and illustrated on the image.  Once you have done that, automatic updating can be done with a button or event macro.  You will need decide which you want to use.  So far as your formula, that seems unnecessarily complex compared to the Filter method, and not something I would use. Perhaps the person who suggested a formula solution to your problem would have a suggestion about that.

Comment: thanks again, can u pls show the example to assign it to button click ....basically i am a web developer, new to excel

Comment: thanks !  i got i want but how to change it dynamically if the user changes the date, if i can i add it to any vba module and add it to macro, if yes, how...pls bear with me.. i am just little bit away to my desired action in excel sheet

Comment: I've added some macro code to my answer.  To attach it to a button, see Excel HELP for "Add a button or command button to a worksheet".  For an event Macro, first adapt the macro to your specific requirements, then post back.

Answer (score 1):

If `Name` is in A1 then:

```
=IF(AND(C$10>=B2,C$10<=C2),A2,"")
```

in D2 and copied down to suit may serve.