# Excel: Search for specific dates within 2 date ranges

Tags: excel, date

I have been looking and looking for a solution for my question.

I have 3 columns with job number, a start date and end date in dd/mm/yyyy format (these represent jobs ie we worked on that specific job number between those dates), I also have a reference table in another work sheet with public holidays.

I would like to be able to write a formula that would be able to return the number of times a public holiday landed between the start and end date for each job number.

What would be the best formula to help me with my issue?

Thank you

Comment: May be this would help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862132/how-to-find-data-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS($L$3:$L$16, ">=" & B2,$L$3:$L$16, "<" & C2)
```

Where,
 1. $L$3 is the starting cell of the column date of public holidays 
 2. $L$16 is the last cell of the column date of public holidays
 3. B2 is the cell of column "start date" of the job
 4. C2 is the cell of column "end date" of the job